# knowing when job is crashed (or listen to a job stoppage)

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler

I just need to know how to run some code when Job is stopped (crashed or completed).

to have interface or listener to those events.

and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

you can implement a custom listener that extends [JobListenerSupport](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/api/2.1.7/org/quartz/listeners/JobListenerSupport.html)

```
public class BatchJobRunTimeLogger extends JobListenerSupport {

private Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(BatchJobRunTimeLogger.class);

@Override
public String getName() {
    return "BatchJobRunTimeLogger";
}

public void jobWasExecuted(JobExecutionContext context, JobExecutionException jobException) {
    String jobName = context.getJobDetail().getKey().getName();
    long runTime = context.getJobRunTime();

    LOGGER.info("JobName={}  took RunTime={}", jobName, runTime);
}
```

}